# Bootstrap Form inline only works full screen not scaled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Not sure why this is happening but when I have the page in full screen the form-inline works great.  But as soon as I start scaling it down the label goes on top of the form.

Using bootstrap 3

```
 <row>
     <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
            <label>Start:<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ start_length }}" id="bar"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 pull-right form-group">
            <label>End: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ end_length }}" id="bar1"></label>
        </div>
    </form>
 </row>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/interneteur/L9ty8hb0/)

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.inline{
    display:inline-block!important;
    width:auto!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.4/custom/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<row>
                 <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start:<input type="text" class="form-control inline" placeholder="0" id="bar"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>End: <input type="text" class="form-control inline" placeholder="45" id="bar1"></label>
                    </div>
                </form>
             </row>
```

Comment: That works fine when it is in full screen, but once you scale does the exact same thing as what I posted. It shows [this](http://i.imgur.com/R2bNT7j.png)

Comment: It is mentioned in the docs as "Inline form
Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a <form>) for left-aligned and inline-block controls. This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide." Read this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Ah I see, so I guess I will have to find another way to have it display the label next to it.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't scale it.  Sigh.  I'm just going to have to find another way around this.